# Adding Row to Table Under Certain Conditions in R

Tags: r, matrix, confusion-matrix

I have the following two vectors:

```
> pred
 [1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
[19] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"

> act
 [1] "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
[19] "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "1"
```

I am trying to make a confusion matrix with these two by doing this:

```
> conf = table(pred, act)
> conf 
    act
pred  0  1
   1 12 19
```

Obviously, since every vector of the `pred` vector is 1, this confusion matrix only has one row; the first entry is the number of incorrect classifications, and the second entry is the correct number of classifications.

I am doing these confusion matrices for several situations, and in general, they are 2 x 2, with the first row corresponding to the correct and incorrect classifications to 0. However, under these conditions, the confusion matrix is 1 x 2, so I would like to make this matrix 2 x 2 with 0's in the first row. Something like this:

```
> matrix(c(rep(0, 2), conf[1, 1], conf[1, 2]), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]   12   19
```

I want to make it so that if the dimensions of this confusion matrix are 1 x 2, it gets changed into a 2 x 2 matrix, and otherwise gets left alone. I tried this:

```
> conf = ifelse(nrow(conf) == 1, 
                matrix(c(rep(0, 2), conf[1, 1], conf[1, 2]), 
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE), 
                conf)
```

However, when I try this, I get the following result:

```
> conf
[1] 0
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert `pred` and `act` as `factors` with `levels` as `union` of both

```
all_levels <- union(act, pred)

pred <- factor(pred, levels = all_levels)
act <- factor(act, levels = all_levels)
table(pred, act)

#    act
#pred  0  1
#   0  0  0
#   1 12 19
```